# Two questions about transfinite powers of a ring or ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

Reading Jacobson's 1945 paper on the radical and semi-simplicity for arbitrary rings.  Loving the paper and understanding it well until I hit the following snag. He defines transfinite powers of a ring $A$ as follows.

$A^{1}=A$

$A^{\alpha+1}=A^{\alpha}A$

For a limit ordinal $\beta$

$A^{\beta}=join\{{A^{\alpha},\alpha<\beta}\}$.

I am having trouble right away using the example of even integers. There, it seems the powers are descending. Yet join is an "increasing" operation. Should I not compute $A^{\infty}$ as the ring generated by $A$, the ring of even integers, $A^2$, the ring of multiples of 4, $A^3$, the multiples of 8,... etc?

Perhaps I am not clear on the definition of join. I am missing something. I think $A^{\infty}=\{0\}$.

Jacobson then says there is a least ordinal, $\rho$, such that $A^{\rho}=A^{\rho+1}$. I know the ordinals are well ordered, but how do we know, in general, that the set of $\rho$ for which $A^{\rho}=A^{\rho+1}$ is non-empty? Jacobson does not assume the Descending Chain Condition (at least not explicitly).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is Jacobson's use of "join" is simply incompatible with modern lattice theory (Birkhoff seems to have collected and developed modern lattice theory between 1938 and 1968, and Jacobson's paper published 1945).  Presumably, his "join" is equivalent to intersection.

As for your second question, you can use Cantor's diagonal argument to show that $A^\rho = A^{\rho+1}$ for some $\rho \leq 2^{|A|}$ (the DCC, in contrast, is the statement that $\rho$ is finite, which doesn't need to hold)